# Format json data according into csv using linux

Tags: json, awk

I have some **invalid** json data generated by some job in a file and I need to format it to a tabular form

`input.json`

```
{"data":[["data102",0.218],["data103",0.188]],"meta_info":"ドクターｼﾞｬﾙﾄ"}
{"data":[["data606",0.017],["data505",0.016]],"meta_info":"query2"}
.
.
.
```

I need to format it to the following csv form in linux, pref from command line and save it to a csv file

```
Query         DataEle       Score          MId       Rank         Mode
ドクターｼﾞｬﾙﾄ   data102       0.218           6         1            T
ドクターｼﾞｬﾙﾄ   data103       0.188           6         2            T
query2        data606       0.017           6         1            T
query2        data505       0.016           6         2            T
```

Tried using `jq` and `awk`, however since the input is in invalid format, it didn't work

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @Cyrus How does that affect the solution? Please think before downvoting. 
I did search, tried using `awk` as well as `jq` however since the original data is invalid json, it didn't work